# Legato slide, Pulloff, hammer on combo

Tags: electric-guitar, tablature

[image][image]I have been trying to figure out how to play these notes for months.. I don’t know if I’m supposed to do it as 1 pick starting at the 16 then pull off and slide hammer and slide again?? Please help.

Which notes do I fret first and in what order?

Comment: Where is this from? Listening to the original performance could help.

Comment: Really need to see at least the surrounding bars to provide better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting on 16, pull off to 14, slide to 12, hammer on to 14 and slide to 16. I’d suggest following fingering where (1) is the index finger and (3) is the ring finger (or right hand equivalent).

(3)16 P (1)14 S (1)12 S (1)16

The long slur connecting the 16’s at either end is notation for legato. This means in the entire line there is only meant to be one pluck on the first 16.

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely makes so much sense!! You’re the best

Comment: I disagree, there is only one pluck at the beginning, the legato covers the last note which is articulated with the slide from 14 to 16.

Comment: Slide to pluck is a standard technique in electric guitar. There’s objectively no way of knowing John until a bigger screenshot is posted by OP. In the score legato continues from the final 16 to other notes. This infers a second plucking.

Comment: I disagree that slide to pluck is a standard technique. Yes, it gets used, but more often, in a fast passage, there's no need to pluck after the slide, as here.

Comment: It very much is a standard technique it’s name is a “shift slide” and is notated exactly as above. Curious as to how you can justify the ongoing slur if the last note is not meant to be plucked?

Comment: It's impossible to tell if it's a slur or tie from the picture

Comment: @ojs - no, it's not. A slur will join several notes that are of different pitch, as here. A tie has to join notes of the same pitch.

Comment: @Tim there are two arcs in the picture. The fully shown one is a slur. The one to the right that is cut in half could be a tie depending what's on the other end. If you know what is there, please tell how you know.

Comment: @ojs - I only looked at the tab. But, it's an educated guess that the 2nd one will be a tie, looking at the vib. sign above.

Comment: @Tim I would expect it to be a tie too. I was answering to the person above who seemed to think that it's the beginning of next slur and should be picked. The tab suggests it's a tie but this wouldn't be the first time tab and standard notation disagree.

Comment: Looking at the context it’s clear that the part in original question was single slur and only first note is picked.

Answer (score 4):

Pluck 16, pull off to 14. Slide down to 12. Hammer back on to 14. Slide back to 16. There is only one place to pluck - the very first time anything is played. Use whichever fingers you feel work best for you, bear in mind the slides will utilise the same finger each time.

Comment: Wow that is probably going to be a fast note sequence. Thanks Tim